# karma.conf.js does not exist! nodejs error

Tags: node.js, angularjs, gruntjs, karma-jasmine, yeoman-generator-angular

I created an angular app with [yoeman](http://yeoman.io/) scaffolding tool, using the command:

```
yo angular
```

when I run `grunt serve` it outputs my app fine, its when I run `grunt` that I get

> Running "karma:unit" (karma) task ERROR [config]: File
>   /home/ubuntu/karma.conf.js does not exist!

the file is not there but shouldn't this be generated when karma was installed ?

**Versions I am running:**

*npm* 1.4.9

*yo* 1.1.2

*bower* 1.3.4

*node v0.10.28* (I read somewhere this version is best instead of the new one for yoeman)

Comment: Looks like you are looking in ~ for your file this should probably either be ./npm_modules or ~/.something. I dont know any app that installs to ~ by default

Comment: Looking a little bit more location should be declared in your gruntfile. Even if it isnt auto gened should be easy to create manually. Check out the test client in the karma-runner project on github

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are apparently some bugs in the current version of the Angular generator. Here's what I did to fix what it generated:

1. In `Gruntfile.js`, change the path of `karma.conf.js` to `test/karma.conf.js`.
2. Fix syntax errors and missing sections in `karma.conf.js`. See this Gist: https://gist.github.com/kristopherjohnson/f1d7e4d1c31ae3b0899e

Comment: grunt ---force might give you more info

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I didn't find karma.cong.js at all. What I have done is just forcing grunt with

```
grunt --force
```

And then I was getting something like that

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
08 09 2015 13:16:33.928:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-phantomjs-launcher".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
08 09 2015 13:16:33.939:WARN [plugin]: Cannot find plugin "karma-jasmine".
  Did you forget to install it ?
  npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
Warning: No provider for "framework:jasmine"! (Resolving: framework:jasmine) Used --force, continuing.
```

So I was able to figure it out what I was missing.

```
  npm install karma-phantomjs-launcher --save-dev
  npm install karma-jasmine --save-dev
```

Hope this help.